# What does it mean by "Koa does not bundle any middleware within its core"?

Tags: node.js, koa

I was studying the koa framework and the philosophy behind it. On the official website they used this sentence

```
What does it mean by "Koa does not bundle any middleware within its core"?
```

Now I wasn't able to understand how does this actually mean. And I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Searched everywhere on the internet all anyone has done is repeat this sentensce.

Comment: Do you know what a middleware means or what is its purpose?

Comment: It means precisely what it says. https://koajs.com/#application and https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki#middleware. It means core Koa has no middleware of its own.

Answer (score 0):

It means that any middleware you need, you need to install separately. Examples include:

- Middleware for routing
- Middleware for serving static files
- Middleware for parsing HTTP request bodies